# How to search a field when you get the ORA-19011 error?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to do a SQL query to find all items that have a value within a comment field in the databse. However, when I do this I get the following error, which I'm not sure how to resolve:

```
ORA-19011: Character string buffer too small
19011. 00000 -  "Character string buffer too small" 
*Cause:    The string result asked for is too big to return back
*Action:   Get the result as a lob instead
```

The querty I am using is as follows:

```
select *
from 
actionLog al
where comments like '%GEM9_EM_SCFNY_TT%'
```

Any help on how to modify my query would be very much appreciated.

Thanks
Michael

Comment: what type is comments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't been able to find any way to substantiate this, but I suspect that the `like` operator is causing the `CLOB` field `comments` to be implicitly converted to a `varchar2`. Since the `CLOB` is too large, you get the error. You can work around this by using a function designed to work with the `CLOB` datatype instead:

```
SELECT *
FROM   actionlog al
WHERE  DBMS_LOB.INSTR (comments, 'GEM9_EM_SCFNY_TT') <> 0
```

Comment: When doing this I get the following erroring error

ORA-06553: PLS-306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'INSTR'
06553. 00000 -  "PLS-%s: %s"

Comment: The type of comments is XMLTYPE

Answer (score 0):

Since its an XMLTYPE you can use the .getClobVal() function. So your code should work if you do this:

```
select *
from 
actionLog al
where comments.getClobVal() like '%GEM9_EM_SCFNY_TT%'
```