# ORA-19011: Character string buffer too small *Action: Get the result as a lob instead

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle11g

Please see the query below:

```
SELECT '<Incident URN="1">' || dbms_xmlgen.getxmltype ('
SELECT * FROM INCIDENT WHERE (( PERSON_SURNAME LIKE ''Bloggs%'' OR PERSON_SURNAME LIKE ''Bloggs%'')) AND (( FORENAME_1 LIKE ''Fred%'' OR FORENAME_1 LIKE 
''Fred%'') OR ( FORENAME_2 LIKE ''Fred%'' OR FORENAME_2 LIKE ''Fred%'') OR ( FORENAME_3 LIKE ''Fred%'' OR FORENAME_3 LIKE ''Fred%'')) AND (PERSON_DOB = to_date(''1981-11-04'',
''YYYY-MM-DD'')) ORDER BY INC_CR_DTE Desc, INC_NO Desc 
').extract ('ROWSET/ROW/*')  || '</Incident>'as XMLReturned from dual
```

The error I get is:

```
ORA-19011: Character string buffer too small
19011. 00000 -  "Character string buffer too small" 
*Cause:    The string result asked for is too big to return back
*Action:   Get the result as a lob instead
```

I have done some Googling and I found this: http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_ora_19011_character_string_buffer_too_small.htm and this: [How to search a field when you get the ORA-19011 error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23765366/how-to-search-a-field-when-you-get-the-ora-19011-error) but neither helped.  How can I resolve this?

Comment: Can you try SELECT to_clob('')|| ...

Comment: @Mottor, I have tried this: ORA-00936: missing expression

Comment: change .extract('ROWSET/ROW/*') to extract('ROWSET/ROW/*').getClobVal()

Comment: ora-00936 is error in defining the select. Does not mater , use Chrisrs2292 suggestion.